# How can I put some content to the view after it had rendered?

Tags: php, laravel, view

Please Tell me Can I put some content to some div in the view after it had rendered ?

```
    echo view('reply.reply',$result);//Hear preloader working

$reply = new \App\modules\CreditRequest\Controller\CoApplicant();
                $reply =$reply->getReplyTypeAction();

                return $reply;// PUT this content to view to div id-"compose"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you want to simply `echo "Something..."` or `{{ $reply }}` after view is returned, again, you can't because view data is already send thru HTTP and connection is *probably* closed.

Simple solution is to utilize javascript and perform ajax request and populate `id="compose"` element in DOM.

JS & ajax is not specific to Laravel, so you can find plenty solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$content = view('reply.reply',$result)->render();

.. do something

return $content;
```